# JDBC | SQL Anywhere Error -188: Not enough values for host variables

Tags: sql, hibernate, jdbc, sybase

JDBC or Hibernate is showing strange behavior while calling a stored procedure.

**Here is the sample code:**

```
return session.createSQLQuery("select * from pr_ss_coo_10x('31748','NEWRX',null,'5053')")
    ..
    ....tolist();
```

**It is throwing error**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2620)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:336)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1967)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:322)
at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:125)
at com.mps.surescript.repository.impl.SSGetInfoRepoImpl.getBenefitCoordInformation(SSGetInfoRepoImpl.java:79)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
... 76 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException: SQL Anywhere Error -188: Not enough values for host variables
at com.sybase.jdbc3.tds.Tds.a(Unknown Source)
at com.sybase.jdbc3.tds.Tds.nextResult(Unknown Source)
```

However, it is working fine when I fire the same query through SQL Anywhere client. Sybase error code document says

> "You have not provided enough host variables for either the number of
>   bind variables, or the statement, or the number of SELECT list items."

I have checked it twice and the result set is correctly mapped with the Pojo. **What can be the possible root cause for this problem**?

Comment: What is the definition of `pr_ss_coo_10x`?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  a select statement with a where clause. And resultset definition is   `coo_groupid varchar(35),coo_partyname varchar(35),coo_Add1  varchar(35), coo_state  varchar(9), coo_city  varchar(35),  coo_zip  varchar(11), coo_location_code  varchar(3)`

Comment: Well, you seem to have 7 parameters in pr_ss_coo, and you're supplying 4.

Comment: @access_granted These are not parameters. These are resultset definition. Parameters are 4 only.

Answer (score 2):

Bypassing the Hibernate transaction Management did the trick and fetching result set using PreparedStatement.

`Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
      PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
          "select * from pr_ss_coo_10x(@param1=?,@param2=?, @param3=?, @param4=?  )");
   ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();`

This is not a solution, it is just a way around.